# Converting date format gives "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql, sql-server

The date format in the table is YYYYMMDD and I would like to convert it to the following format but it is failing with an error:

`2019-07-23 00:00:00.000`

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here is the statement I'm using:

```
convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, InstallDate0), 23)
```

Comment: If 2012+ use try_convert().   It will return a NULL value if the conversion fails.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the "format" at all? Date and time values, in SQL Server, don't have a "format"; they are binary values. Date and time data types exist in SQL Server for a reason; to store data and time values. Don't store your dates as a `varchar`, it's the **wrong** data type. If you *need* a "format" That's the presentation layers duty to perform. If, for some unknown reason, you can't get your presentation layer to do its job, use a (persisted) computed column to provide the formatted value; but certainly don't store the actual value as a `varchar`.

Comment: You might also try `where InstallDate0 not like '[12][90][0-9][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-3][0-9]'`

Comment: My problem is the date in the table I'm using is data type nvarchar and is in a format that isn't useable (i.e. - 20140908 instead of 2014-09-08 00:00:00.000 and datetime format)

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is the choice of your datatype. `varchar` is the wrong choice. As a result, it seems that you now have some rows where the value of the "date" has been lost, as it can't be converted to a date.

To properly fix this problem, fix your datatype. Firstly I would create a new column to store the bad values:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD BadDate varchar(20); --as it's yyyyMMdd you don't need more than 8 characters, but we'll assume you have some really bad values
UPDATE YourTable 
SET BadDate = InstallDate0
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,InstallDate0) IS NULL;
```

Now that you've done that, time to update the existing column:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET InstallDate0 = CONVERT(varchar(8),TRY_CONVERT(datetime, InstallDate),112);
```

This'll set every value to the `yyyyMMdd` format where the value can be converted. NOw you can alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN InstallDate0 date; --AS it's yyyyMMdd, it seems silly to actually use datetime
```

Now you have a proper `datetime` column.

You'll then need to inspect the values of `BadDate` and *try* to correct them (or admit that any information they held has been lost for ever).

If you "must" have another column with the format, then add a further column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD InstallDate0_f AS CONVERT(varchar(23),InstallDate0,121);
```

Comment: Thanks but I can only do select statements, I can't alter the table.  My problem is the date in the table I'm using is data type nvarchar and is in a format that isn't useable (i.e. - 20140908 instead of 2014-09-08 00:00:00.000 and datetime format)

Comment: How is `20140908` not "useable" @user3009669 ? that is the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`. In fact, the date `2014-09-08 00:00:00.000` is **less** usable with a `datetime` as depending on your language you would get different results. (`BRITISH` would give the date `09 September 2014` while "`ENGLISH`" would give `08 August 2014`).

Comment: I'm trying to use a DATEDIFF statement against the date in the current format and it doesn't work.  I get the error reported, "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: If I try the statement convert(nvarchar(255), convert(datetime, InstallDate0), 23) it returns what I'm looking for but then fails immediately after it returns what I'm looking for with same error reported "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Because you have bad dates, @user3009669; like i said. This is why you should never store a date and time value as a `varchar`m because can (and will) foolishly stores dates like `'20192432'`.

Comment: What do you "it's Microsoft", are you telling me that employees of Microsoft are inserting bad dates into *your* database that has a `varchar` data type instead of a `date` @user3009669? If so, then fix the data type and they can't anymore.

Comment: The table I'm working with is a Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager table in it's SQL database.  Yes, for whatever reason (I can't think of a good one) they used a nvarchar value for the date in the table I'm having an issue with.

Comment: Seems like, that in addition to the fact your are using a `nvarchar` to store dates (doubly as bad, as `yyyyMMdd` will **never** contain a unicode character, so you're using 16 bytes to store a value that could be 3 bytes), and that the users storing the value aren't valid dates. Gordon explains how to find the "bad" values though @user3009669, as well as I; by using `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine where the problems are using `TRY_CONVERT()`.  The problem would seem to be the conversion to a `datetime`, so try this:

```
select InstallDate0
from t
where try_convert(datetime, InstallDate0) is null;
```